# Different sight indicators

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed that when the enemy has visibility of a champion, the indicator above them is different between Warwick's Blood Scent and most (all?) other abilities, such as Cait's trap. Here are screen grabs of the two:

[image: blood scent] [image: Cait's trap]

Is there any functional difference between the two?

Comment: The icon alone won't tell you what condition you're under; you'll have to read the debuff for the specifics!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are specific vision indicators as you have already noticed but you cannot tell whether somthing is true vision (ignores stealth) or just a normal vision (ignores fog of war / bushes). This depends entirely on the spell that is cast.

A Nidalee trap grants vision to a stealthed target and it used to have the same indicator (second picture) as Corkis Phosphorous Bomb (Does not reveal stealth).

If you see such a thing above your head it basically just means that the enemy has vision on this champion.

[Here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth#Invisibility_detection) you can find a list with all stealth detection methods.

[Here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vision#Reveal_enemy_champions_and_their_immediate_surroundings) you can find a list of all vision generating spells. You will notice some of them use the same Icon as stealth detecting ones.

The following Champion spells use individual "marks" for vision.

### The ones not listed use the standard "eyes" that look like this

[image]

**Diana Q (Champion is pierced by a ray of dim light, does not reveal stealth)**
[image]

**Warwick E (Two Red eyes, Does not reveal stealth)**
[image]

**Twisted Fate R (Orange Eye, Does reveal stealth)**
[image]

**Talon Q (Blade above the target, Does not reveal stealth directly but prevents from entering it due to ticking damage)**
[image]

**Nidalee Passive (A yellow triangle, Does reveal stealth)**
[image]

**Rengar R (Not really a mark, but the champion glows red, reveals stealth)**
[image]

Comment: Do they all reveal the area around the champion?

Comment: @clcto Yes they do. But the radius depends on the spell. Usually It's not too big (around 100 units).

Comment: Additionally, with Talon's Q they leave a blood trail so you can see where the stealthed units are going even though you can't actually see them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also notice a difference with the icon displayed by Nidalee. Why? They give different bonuses.

The eye-like icon is used to indicate that you only have vision over the champion, nothing else (Cait's trap and other such abilities).

[Blood scent](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warwick) gives Warwick :

> Toggle: Warwick reveals enemy champions within range with less than
> 50% health.
>
> While any enemies are revealed this way, Warwick has increased
> movement speed

and Nidalee [prowl](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-411-notes)

> Passive - Prowl : SPEEDY CAT Nidalee now receives +10% Movement Speed
> in all directions while Hunting, which increases to +30% movement
> speed toward Hunted targets
>
> KITTY SPEED LIMITS At any one time,
> Nidalee can never receive more than a total of +30% Movement Speed
> from The Hunt and Brush movement speed bonuses

There are other specific icons (like [Twisted Fate's ult](https://www.google.ca/search?q=twisted+fate+ult+icon&tbm=isch&imgil=bKjet0Ow-BgItM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcSsWedvQvBk9vs5piF2q54A9wqAdKIUJvdQE1V3UziG5DyyePHO_w%253B1280%253B860%253B_BaR7jNgpRT6jM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.eclypsia.com%25252Fen%25252Flol%25252Fguide%25252Fchampion%25252F18&source=iu&usg=__El7Gd8c-vbSERbnsW4Fn_N5znFw%3D&sa=X&ei=5e-7U6OIFMGsyASEkIK4Cg&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQ9QEwBQ&biw=1596&bih=779#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=bKjet0Ow-BgItM%253A%3B_BaR7jNgpRT6jM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstatic.eclypsia.com%252Fpublic%252Fupload%252Fcke%252FLoL%252FGuides%252Ftwisted%252520fate%252FR-Large.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.eclypsia.com%252Fen%252Flol%252Fguide%252Fchampion%252F18%3B1280%3B860)) so here's a [list of the spells giving vision](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vision#Reveal_enemy_champions_and_their_immediate_surroundings) (thanks Jutschge).

Comment: One more that comes to mind is TFs ult